# I am not getting the alert javascript on my controller page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-2

I have this code in my ActionResult

```
public ActionResult Copy( int bvVariableid ) {
            var iReturn = _bvRepository.CopyBenefitVariable( bvVariableid, CurrentHealthPlanId, CurrentControlPlanId, _bvRepository.GetSecInfo( ).UserId, IsNascoUser());
            if (iReturn == -999)
                return new JavaScriptResult() { Script = "alert(Unique variable name could not be created');" };
            if( iReturn != -1 )
                return Json( new { RedirectUrl = string.Format( "/BvIndex/Index/{0}?bvIndex-mode=select", iReturn ) } );
            return RedirectToRoute( "Error" );
        }
```

This is the code i have in my View.

```
CopyBenefitVariable = function (bvId, bvName) {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to copy from the Benefit Variable ' + bvName + ' ?')) {
                $.post(
              "/BvIndex/Copy/",
              { bvVariableid: bvId },
              function (data) {
                  window.location = data.RedirectUrl;
              }, "json");
            }
        };
```

When IReturn is -999 I am not getting the JavaScriptResult alert box on my page.

is that something I am doing wrong here?

Can any body help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is likely stemming from your client-side JavaScript.  The .post() method in ajax is actually a shortcut for:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

So your client-side code is telling jQuery to interpret the result as a json object (even though you sent back a script).

```
$.post(
  "/BvIndex/Copy/",  // url
  { bvVariableid: bvId }, // data
  function (data) {
     window.location = data.RedirectUrl;  // success
  },
  "json" // dataType
);
```

I would change your code to look like this:

```
public ActionResult Copy( int bvVariableid ) {
    var iReturn = _bvRepository.CopyBenefitVariable( bvVariableid, CurrentHealthPlanId, CurrentControlPlanId, _bvRepository.GetSecInfo( ).UserId, IsNascoUser());

    if (iReturn == -999)
        return new Json(new { type = "msg", data = "Unique variable name could not be created" });
    if( iReturn != -1 )
        return Json( new { type = "url", data = string.Format( "/BvIndex/Index/{0}?bvIndex-mode=select", iReturn ) } );
        return RedirectToRoute( "Error" );
}
```

And your view code should look like this:

```
CopyBenefitVariable = function (bvId, bvName) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to copy from the Benefit Variable ' + bvName + ' ?')) {
        $.post(
          "/BvIndex/Copy/",
          { bvVariableid: bvId },
          function (data) {
              if (data.type == "url") {
                  window.location = data.RedirectUrl;
              } else if (data.type == "msg") {
                  alert(data.data);
              }
          }, "json");
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I thing, there is a bug in this line:

```
return new JavaScriptResult() { Script = "alert(Unique variable name could not be created');" };
```

Corrected :

```
  return new JavaScriptResult() { Script = "alert('Unique variable name could not be created');" };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mark down my answer if you like, but it is generally accepted that the `JavaScriptResult` was a bad move on the ASP.NET MVC team's part. That being said, your sample already returns a `Json` Action Result for one of your conditions. You could do the same for both items. If you altered your JSON object like:

```
 return Json( new { success = bool,  RedirectUrl = value } );
```

Then you could change your client function to something like:

```
function (data) {
  if(data.success === true) {
    window.location = data.RedirectUrl;
  } else {
    alert('Unique variable name could not be created');
  }
}
```

I know it doesn't directly address the issue with `JavaScriptResult`, but it should get the intended result of the code.